# Unable to get checkbox value in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating checkboxes using jquery and then appending the checkboxes inside a div tag. Now, I want to get the values of the checkboxes when I click on a button but for some reason, I am getting only "on" instead of the actual value. What could I be doing wrong ?

HTML:

```
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label>Select a category</label><br>
</div>


<button style="background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black; border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;" id="clr_btn">Clear
            </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/getcategory",
            type: "GET",

            success: function (result) {
                var result = result.results;

                if (result.length > 0) {


                    $.each(result, function (i, res) {
                        var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" class="chklist" name="chke"  id="chk_'+i+'" val ='+res.name+'/>'+res.name+"<br />");
                        $('.checkboxes').append($chk)


                    });



                }


            },
            error: function (error) {


            }
        });
    })


// button click event

  $('#clr_btn').click(function (e) {


  alert($("input[name=chke]:checked").map(
     function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));

    })
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code so we can replicate your issue. You mention a "button's" `click` event, but where is the button?

Comment: Can you try to get the value with the "this.val()" instead of "this.value"?

Comment: @HugoESachez:- error - this.val() is not function

Comment: @RemyPhrentch `$(this).val()` work?

Comment: @holaymolay:- I still keep getting on,on instead of the value from the selected checkbox

Comment: What is `result`? Please add enough code so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: holaymolay you're right, @RemyPhrentch can u check please the value of the checkbox when you asign it?

Comment: @HugoESachez:- Yes you are right. I was using val instead of value and also not using proper delimeters. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML literal string, you weren't setting the `value` of the elements, you were setting the `val` attribute, which doesn't exist.

```js
// Dummy variable to make loop run
let result = [{name:"foo"},{name:"bar"},{name:"baz"}];

$.each(result, function (i, res) {
  var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" class="chklist" name="chke"'  
                + 'id="chk_' + i + '" value =' + res.name + '>' + 
                res.name + "<br />");
  $('.checkboxes').append($chk)
});

// JQuery recommends using ".on()" to bind events now:
$('#clr_btn').on("click", function (e) {
  alert($("input[name='chke']:checked").map(
    function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
});
```

```css
#clr_btn {
        background-color: #e7e7e7; 
        color: black; border: none;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label>Select a category</label><br>
</div>

<!-- Don't use inline CSS. -->
<button id="clr_btn" type="button">Clear</button>
```